# Homework translation

Tags: translation

My homework is to answer this question.

> なんようび　に　日本語　の　クラス　が　ありますか

I believe this question is asking "What day do i have Japanese class on?"

I want to say "I have Japanese class on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday."
Is this how I would say that?

> 日本語　の　クラス　 に 　げつようび　と　すいようび　と　きんようび　あります。

Thanks

Comment: You said あります**が**  did you mean あります**か**?

Comment: @ajsmart yes sorry

Answer (score 3):

Almost, but not quite.  Your answer is almost saying, "The class *has* Mon., Wed., and Fri."  What you need to say is, "As for the class, it is on Mon., Wed., Fri.".

Protip:  If you want to impress your teacher, you can contract `げつようび　と　すいようび　と　きんようび` into `げっすいきん`.

Comment: So should I say - nihongo no kurasu wa getsuyoubi to suiyoubi to kinyoubi arimasu？

Comment: + 1 for the protip ;)

Comment: @bassxzero, you should either use *ni arimasu* or *desu* to conclude your sentence. *arimasu* alone does not work.